# Sql Select by join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables PurchaseDetails and SaleDetails. Both tables have a column with same name i.e 'Quantity'. I want to get balance by getting sum of both columns and then subtract them. I  am using query as

```
select (sum(pd.Quantity)-sum(sd.Quantity)) as Balance 
from PurchaseDetails pd  
join SalesDetails sd on sd.ProductId=pd.ProductId 
where pd.ProductId='Pro_1'
```

But It returns a false calculation like '22205' while the actual return should be '158'.

I have tried this query also but it also gives the same erroneous results

```
select sum(pd.quantity)-sum(sd.quantity) 
from PurchaseDetails pd,salesdetails sd 
where pd.ProductId=sd.ProductId and pd.productid='Pro_1'
```

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to avoid the duplicates you're getting by combining all matching rows in pd with all matching rows in sd is probably to use two separate selects - one for each table - and `UNION ALL` the resulting rows;

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) Balance FROM (
  SELECT  Quantity FROM PurchaseDetails WHERE ProductId='Pro_1' 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -Quantity FROM SalesDetails    WHERE ProductId='Pro_1' 
)z;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4248/2).

Comment: thanks very much... it works. And happy to have this a different idea :)

Comment: could you please explain it :-) I would love to understand your solution so that i could use it/implement it in the future!

Comment: Basically I just get all rows from PurchaseDetails with a positive quantity, and all rows from SalesDetails with a negative quantity. Getting a balance is then just a matter of summing up the quantities.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select (sum(p.Quantity)-(select sum(s.Quantity) from salesdetails s where s.ProductId='Pro_1' ))as balance from PurchaseDetails p  where p.ProductId='Pro_1'
```